# How do I install PyTorch 1.0 using pip?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

In order to use Facebook's LASER embeddings, I need to install a version of PyTorch that meets the following requirement:

`torch<2.0.0 and >=1.0.1.post2`

The PyTorch [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) lists instructions for installing any number of versions that meet this requirement.  However, when I run, say,

`pip3 install torch==1.13.1`

I get the following:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.13.1 (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.13.1`

I am not much of a Python developer, so I'm not sure what I am missing here.  I have searched around quite a bit for an answer, but previous answers to questions about similar issues lead to dead links, or instructions on how to use conda to resolve (which is not an option for me, I'm afraid).

For what its worth, I am running Python 3.11.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python version is too new. PyTorch versions 1.x are not available for Python 3.11. Install an older version of Python, like 3.10.

PyTorch 1.13.1 is available for Python 3.10, 3.9, 3.8, and 3.7. On Linux, it is also available for Python 3.11, so I assume you are not on a Linux machine.

In the error message

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.13.1 (from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.13.1

you see "from versions: 2.0.0, 2.0.1" because you are using Python 3.11 and only PyTorch versions 2.0.0 and 2.0.1 are available for that version of Python.